# how do I save or update an object in a thread safe way using JPA?

Tags: java, jpa, persistence

How can I make the code below thread safe?

```
objects.forEach(object -> {
            Boolean objectExists = objectRepository.existsByObjectNameAndFormatAndLocale(
                    object.getObjectName(),
                    object.getFormat(),
                    object.getLocale());
            if (!objectExists){
                objectRepository.save(object);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

please put below code inside synchronized block , to execute below current class object lock is required.

```
 synchronized (this) {
      //code 
    }
```

hope it will work for you

Comment: what if I have 2 server instances?

Comment: create static synchronized method,it will required class level lock

Answer (score 1):

Your "forEach" needs to run atomic, so how about

```
private synchronized void saveIfNew(YourObjectClass obj) {
    boolean objectExists = objectRepository.existsByObjectNameAndFormatAndLocale(
                object.getObjectName(),
                object.getFormat(),
                object.getLocale());
    if (!objectExists){
        objectRepository.save(object);
    }
}

objects.forEach(this::saveIfNew);
```

There are much better and more advanced at making things thread-safe, so some might object to making the entire "saveIfNew" method synchronized, but it's a good place to start.

Comment: what if I have 2 server instances?

Comment: If you have two server instances, you need a locking mechanism on the database. Either aquire a row-lock in existsByObjectNameAndFormatAndLocale, or use a repeatable-read transaction level.